# How can I prove the support of $\sigma$ is contained in a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

**My problem:**

Suppose $\sigma : I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a biregular curve parametrized by arc length, having constant curvature $k_0>0$.

I would like to prove that the support of $\sigma$ is contained in a sphere with radius $R>0$ if and only if $k_0 > \frac 1 R$ and torsion $\tau$ is zero.

**My attempt:**

I observed that if $\|\sigma(s)\|=R$ then $\langle \sigma,\sigma' \rangle=0$, $\langle \sigma'',\sigma' \rangle=0$ and $\langle \sigma''',\sigma'' \rangle=0$ but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: This is wrong. What about a great circle in a sphere of radius $R$? Do you know about normal curvature? If not, I recommend using the Frenet equations.